# Tables created via DDL in UCanAccess cannot be opened in Access itself

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, windows-7-x64, ucanaccess

I have been able to successfully create MS Access database tables from Java using the UCanAccess 2.0.6 driver. However, I am subsequently unable to open up the tables from MS Access (Microsoft Office 2007, Windows 7 64-bit), with MS Access throwing the error :

> Reserved Error (-5001); there is no message for this error.

The exact same CREATE TABLE statement when used from within MS Access itself results in no problems. The strange part is, the tables are successfully created and data can be successfully added AND retrieved by query. So the tables are there in the underlying database, but Access isn't able to open them.

If it helps, one of the create statements I'm using is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tblMain (
        ID COUNTER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        Project INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        ItemNumber INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL, 
        ItemName TEXT NOT NULL, 
        ItemDescription MEMO NOT NULL, 
        OriginatorPerson TEXT NOT NULL, 
        DueDate DATETIME NOT NULL, 
        Closed YESNO NOT NULL, 
        ClosingComments MEMO NOT NULL, 
        Priority YESNO NOT NULL, 
        AssignedToCompany TEXT NOT NULL, 
        AssignedToPerson TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this problem, neither with Access 2007 nor with Access 2010.
All works fine also with Access 2003. But it might happen with some access version...
It looks very similar to an issue that  another user reported in the UCanAccess forum and that I fixed (yet, in that case, I wasn't able to reproduce this issue):
http://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/5a57b955/.

I'm pretty sure it's about the way  UCanaccess(using the underlying jackcess) persists the column properties (e.g, default values, "required"  and so on).
Could you try to re-execute your DDL avoiding to set  "not null" where not needed, so on the column ID(Counter and PK)? And please, let me know your findings, I haven't another way to definitively fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to grant privileges to admin:

```
GRANT SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
ON tblMain
TO Admin;
```

Run that query using UCanAccess 2.0.6 driver.